# MacBook Pro A1278 keyboard works but power button doesn't

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, power

I have a MacBook Pro (mid 2012) A1278. All the keys work except the power button. I've tried different keyboards (i.e., plugging in internal keyboards to test the power button). None of the keyboards seem to trigger the power button. I tried resetting using (command+option+p+r). I have not attempted an SMC reset.

Comment: SMC reset shouldn't hurt anything, if you're reluctant because of that concern. I take your description to mean that you've disassembled the MacBook Pro to connect different internal keyboards. Power button still doesn't work if keyboard slightly out of position?

Comment: I didn't actually remove the keyboard but, instead, unplugged the internal keyboard and plugged in another internal one and let it hang outside the case. I can't really perform an SMC reset because it seems there is no signal coming from the power button. I ordered some new keyboards (I needed some for other reasons) and I'll be sure to test a good keyboard. The other thing I can try is cleaning the keyboard connector (rubbing alcohol?). The connector appears to be in perfect shape. All the keys on the keyboard work except the power button.

Comment: I've tried two keyboards. It could be they are both bad. I'll update once the replacement keyboards come. Then I'll know for sure what the issue is.

Comment: The issue was the keyboard. After replacing the keyboard, it worked. Very strange as usually, a damaged keyboard would usually be more obvious.